# Replicate iPad's native calendar in app

Tags: ipad, calendar

I want to replicate the iPad native calendar in my app, where I can select date/add events/drag events/ reschedule etc. I have seen some libs like taiku and kal but none of them replicates calendar similar to iPad. I found couple of applications which uses iPad style calender but not sure what all components are they using. Let me know if someone knows a library (even paid) or how to implement it (scrollViews? tableviews?)

[Calendar](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/perlow/ipad-at-work-the-essential-guide-for-business-users/13758)

[Calendar-Salesbag](http://www.isalesbag.com/features)

-anoop

Comment: Did you ever find an iPad Calendar?  I am also looking!!

Comment: Nope I haven't, the requirement was taken off :) so didn't analyse further . I guess with UICollectionView and EventKit you should be able to create one (though I haven't tried :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found this....looks good

http://maniacdev.com/2014/04/example-code-a-reproduction-of-the-ios-7-ipad-calendar

-anoop